# Postgres returning unexpected result only when deployed to Heroku (Flask)

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, heroku

I'm having a strange problem.
Here is the route in question:

[image: Route Screenshot]

When I test locally(http://127.0.0.1:5000/) and connect to the postgres URI (the one supplied by Heroku) I get the results intended from this query. Which look like this
[image: Anticipated Results]
It is not until I try hitting the endpoint from the deployed(https://appname.herokuapp.com/) do I get a different result. Which looks like this:

[image: No idea why this is happening]

Inside of the if statement: if it returns true then month just equals last month and the current month separated by a comma like this: 3,4

I have tested out the query on the heroku server by removing the month variable entirely and replacing it with just: (3,4) and it works as expected, so it has to have something to do with the f string/variable injection.  I cannot figure out what's wrong, or why it's only a problem on Heroku. I have double checked that all files on Heroku are up to date.

Any help is sooo appreciated.

```
@app.route('/thisweek', methods=['GET'])
def get_weeks_moods():
    today = Today()
    if today.is_new_month():
        month = f"{today.get_yesterday()['month']},{today.month}"
    else:
        month = today.month

# Raw sql requirement
    data = db.session.execute(
        f"SELECT m.id, m.date, coalesce(m.moodrating, 0) as moodrating, m.comment, c.day_of_week FROM mood m RIGHT JOIN calendar c ON m.date=c.day_id WHERE c.week_of_year={today.week} AND c.day_of_week <> 0 AND month IN ({month}) AND year={today.year} UNION (SELECT m.id, m.date, coalesce(m.moodrating, 0) AS moodrating, m.comment, c.day_of_week FROM mood m RIGHT JOIN calendar c on m.date=c.day_id WHERE c.week_of_year={today.week - 1} AND c.day_of_week={0} AND c.month IN ({month}) AND c.year={today.year}) ORDER BY day_of_week")

    return jsonify({'result': [dict(row) for row in data]})
```

Comment: Ensure that on your development environment and production environment you are using the same Python version. Also lock your PyPI libraries to a version. The functionalities may have slightly changed leading to different outputs.

Comment: Heroku's runtime is 3.7.2.  My local machine is running 3.8.0